# pyvisa: what does interface_type mean?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble reading from an instrument with an RS232 connection.
I am using pyvisa.
I want to make sure python knows that my instrument is an RS232 instrument.

when I print "SerialInstrument.interface_type" I get "4"
What does 4 mean? does this mean python sees an RS232 device?
I've looked through the documentation but I haven't seen anything that can help me interpret values from this command and many other pyvisa commands.

Can anyone help me out? or direct me to some documentation that will?

Thanks,

Comment: why dont you use pyserial ? I think thats what most people needing serial communication do ...

Comment: I think that's a good idea. I wanted to use pyvisa because I have other code for other instruments using pyvisa but I will probably give up on it soon and use pyserial.

Comment: yup. It works perfectly using pyserial. There must be some default value in pyvisa "SerialInstruments" that is screwing everything up but I haven't figured out what it is.  Thanks for your help.